# Can you convert tokio_postgres::config::Config to connection string?

Tags: rust, tokio-postgres

I want to establish a database connection with [tokio_postgres](https://docs.rs/tokio-postgres/latest/tokio_postgres/) crate. I created a [Config](https://docs.rs/tokio-postgres/latest/tokio_postgres/config/struct.Config.html) object with a connection configuration. However, [connect](https://docs.rs/tokio-postgres/latest/tokio_postgres/fn.connect.html) function takes connection string (`&str`) as an argument. In the docs I couldn't find any way to convert it to (`str`). Is manually building a connection string an only option?

I also tried to use `Display` trait

```rust
let mut db_config = Config::new();
db_config.
    host("localhost").
    user("admin").
    port(5432).
    password("secret_password").
    dbname("admin");

let (client, connection) =
    tokio_postgres::connect(format!("{}", db_config), NoTls).await.unwrap();
```

But without success

```
tokio_postgres::connect(format!("{}", db_config), NoTls).await.unwrap()                                            
                                      ^^^^^^^^^ `Config` cannot be formatted with the default formatter
   
= help: the trait `std::fmt::Display` is not implemented for `Config`
```

Comment: `Config` has a [`connect`](https://docs.rs/tokio-postgres/latest/tokio_postgres/config/struct.Config.html#method.connect) method. I guess you should use that rather than the freestanding function.

Comment: @Jmb Works! That's exactly what I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at [the source code for `tokio_postgres::connect`](https://docs.rs/tokio-postgres/latest/src/tokio_postgres/lib.rs.html#187-196), you can see that it first parses its `&str` argument into a `Config`, then calls [`Config::connect`](https://docs.rs/tokio-postgres/latest/tokio_postgres/config/struct.Config.html#method.connect) on the result. Since you already have a `Config`, you can call its `connect` method directly:

```
let (client, connection) = Config::new()
    .host("localhost")
    .user("admin")
    .port(5432)
    .password("secret_password")
    .dbname("admin")
    .connect(NoTls)
    .await
    .unwrap();
```